# Clarification on Java Serialization

Tags: java

I am learning Serialization and came across this function (in Externalization).

```
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput oi) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
```

I understand that the method creates an object named oi of type ObjectOutput for writing instance variables to the object. When I wanted to learn more about the class ObjectOutput, I was surprised that ObjectOutput is an interface! I thought Java does not allow objects to be created of type interface. Please let me know why this is the case or correct me if I have understood something wrong.

Comment: ObjectOutput is not created here. It's the argument to the method so it is provided by the caller. And the object can be of type ObjectOutput as long as the object provided implements the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as `trappski` pointed out in the comments, `writeExternal` doesn't create anything. `ObjectOutput` is a parameter passed into it by whatever code is calling `writeExternal`.

The trick with interfaces is that they're a "contract". You can't create objects from interfaces, but you can create classes that implement the interface, and then create objects from those classes. You can then use objects of those classes that implement the interface anywhere that is expecting the interface.

In this case, if you have a class `BigObjectOutput` that implements `ObjectOutput` like so:

```
class BigObjectOutput implements ObjectOutput {
  // code...
}
```

then you can create an object of type `BigObjectOutput` like this:

```
BigObjectOutput bigObject = new BigObjectOutput;
```

And pass it into your method because `BigObjectOutput` implements `ObjectOutput`:

```
writeExternal(bigObject);
```

Why would you want to do this? So that you can pass in any object whose type implements `ObjectOutput`:

```
class LittleObjectOutput implements ObjectOutput {
  // code...
}

LittleObjectOutput littleObject = new LittleObjectOutput();

writeOutput(littleObject);
```

So your `writeOutput` is more useful if it accepts any object whose type implements the `OutputObject` interface than if it only took `BigObjectOutput`s.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation @Emma Burrows, but in your example are you trying to say `code`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your explanation @Emma. Did you mean to say                              class LittleObjectOutput extends BigObjectOutput implements ObjectOutput {
  // code...
}

LittleObjectOutput littleObject = new LittleObjectOutput();

writeExternal(littleObject);

- meaning that the function will be useful if it can be used by the parent as well as the child?

Comment: No, my example was that both `BigObjectOutput` and `LittleObjectOutput` implement the interface. They don't need to extend each other. The key here is that they both implement the interface, and can therefore both be used in the method that expects that interface.